# How to write a function that increases the salary of the employee with the lowest salary?

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function that increases the salary of the employee with the lowest salary. It should: receive data on all employees, find the employee with the lowest salary, send a request for a salary increase to this employee by 20%, if the request was successful - send a notification about the salary increase to the employee with the text

> Hello, `<name>`! Congratulations, your new salary is `<new salary>`!

If the request fails, send error data to the administrator. Should
always return a resolved promise with a boolean value: true if the
increase was successful, false otherwise. All functions for
getting/changing data are asynchronous and return promises.

I can not pass the test "in case of an error in increasing the salary, it should send a notification to the administrator, but not to the user", how can I do it?

```js
function increaseSalary() {
 return api.getEmployees()
  .then(employeeData => {
    const [minSalaryEmployee] = employeeData.reduce(([minEmployee, minSalary], employee) => {
      const {salary} = employee;
      return (salary < minSalary
        ? [employee, salary]
        : [minEmployee, minSalary]
      );
    }, [null, Infinity]);
    const {id, salary: oldSalary} = minSalaryEmployee;
    const newSalary = oldSalary * 1.2;
    return {id, salary: newSalary};
  })
   .then(({id, salary}) => api.setEmployeeSalary(id, salary))
   .then(({name, id, salary}) => api.notifyEmployee(id, `Hello, ${name}! Congratulations, your new salary is ${salary}!`))
   .catch(e => api.notifyAdmin(e));
}

const api = {
  _employees: [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alex', salary: 120000 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Fred', salary: 110000 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Bob', salary: 80000 },
  ],

  getEmployees() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(this._employees.slice());
    });
  },

  setEmployeeSalary(employeeId, newSalary) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this._employees = this._employees.map((employee) =>
        employee.id !== employeeId
          ? employee
          : {
            ...employee,
            salary: newSalary,
          }
      );
      resolve(this._employees.find(({ id }) => id === employeeId));
    });
  },

  notifyEmployee(employeeId, text) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(true);
    });
  },

  notifyAdmin(error) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      resolve(true);
    });
  },

  setEmployees(newEmployees) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this._employees = newEmployees;
      resolve();
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: What is not working exactly?

Comment: @kissu, I can not pass the test "in case of an error in increasing the salary, it should send a notification to the administrator, but not to the user"

Comment: Yeah, that part I got. Was mainly looking for more details from your side.

Comment: The promises here never reject, so I'm not sure how they're testing failure. Is it possible they're using a false return rather than a throw?

Comment: @kissu, unfortunately that's the only problem.

Comment: @ggorlen, I think I need to do one more THEN before CATCH and return TRUE in it, but I don’t fully understand how to write it

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess the test suite isn't mocking `api.notifyEmployee` to throw, but rather to resolve to false. You can try handling this as follows:

```js
// same
.then(({name, id, salary}) =>
   api.notifyEmployee(id, `Hello, ${name}! Congratulations, your new salary is ${salary}!`)
)
.then(success => {
  if (!success) {
    notifyAdmin("some message");
  }

  return success;
})
```

Another possible interpretation of the prompt suggests that the "request" that might fail is `api.setEmployeeSalary`, which may return falsey if the request wasn't approved. Under this interpretation, you might try:

```js
// same
.then(({id, salary}) => api.setEmployeeSalary(id, salary))
.then(employee => {
  if (employee) {
    return api.notifyEmployee(id, `Hello, ${name}! Congratulations, your new salary is ${salary}!`));
  }

  return api.notifyAdmin(e).then(() => false);
})
```

If neither of these do the trick, then I'm not sure what other interpretation could be possible. I'd try to find a resource that might clarify their return value and throw contracts under success and failure scenarios.

Answer (score -2):

```js
function increaseLowestSalary(employees) {
  // find the employee with the lowest salary
  let lowestSalary = Infinity;
  let lowestSalaryEmployee;
  for (const employee of employees) {
    if (employee.salary < lowestSalary) {
      lowestSalary = employee.salary;
      lowestSalaryEmployee = employee;
    }
  }

  // increase the lowest salary
  lowestSalaryEmployee.salary *= 1.1;
}

const employees = [  { name: 'Alice', salary: 10000 },  { name: 'Bob', salary: 20000 },  { name: 'Charlie', salary: 15000 },];

increaseLowestSalary(employees);
console.log(employees);  // logs [{ name: 'Alice', salary: 11000 }, { name: 'Bob', salary: 20000 }, { name: 'Charlie', salary: 15000 }]
```

Comment: This totally removes the async API and has basically nothing to do with OP's question.

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer, @Pranjal Tiwari .